# Connecting my Android phone to the DDMS SDK utility

Tags: android, screenshot, device

I am trying to use the SDK's DDMS utility to capture screens off my Droid X.

I have installed the Java JDK and the Android SDK. I set up the USB driver on my Windows laptop and connected my Droid X to the USB port. Windows XP can see the Droid just fine in Windows Explorer as a removable USB device, but the DDMS utility shows no devices.

Running "adb devices" in a DOS window lists no devices either.

Yes, the java.exe location has been added to my PATH.
Yes, the Droid is set to allow USB debugging.

So why can't DDMS see my phone?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. It was resolved by manual installation of drivers from android-sdk-windows\usb_driver

Answer (score 2):

Try to download PDANet. Some devices don't work with usb drivers provided by Google.
Samsung Galaxy S2 (mine) is one of them. Resolved using PDANet.

Answer (score 0):

ddms should see your phone, It does with my nexus on windows xp. Have you tried restarting the ADB? sometimes I have to restart it 3 or 4 times before getting it to work. And when I have the emulator or Eclipse open at the same time, It is sometimes even worse. Try "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" to see if it make any difference...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was solved after I plugged the device on a different USB port, as recommended by [Android device not showing up in DDMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928779/android-device-not-showing-up-in-ddms)

Comment: Similar for me--I had to switch the USB cable that I was using.  The other one showed "charging" on the phone but apparently would not allow data transfer.